# JQuery .get() not returning HTML from Perl script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get

I'm having a small iussue.  I've just started playing with JQuery .get() to call a pl script and return data from the script.  I've got this functioning for email validation currently using:

```
$('#billemail').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $.get('./ajax_email_check.pl',{'email':$('#billemail').val() },function(data){
            if (data == "Not Valid") {
                    alert ("Billing email is " + data + "!");
            }
            });
    }
});
```

The above works fine.  Now I'm trying to return some HTML that is generated, printed and returned based on the user selecting a drop down option and pressing a button.  It looks like I'm getting a null return rather than no return.  If I run the pl script it returns what I'm printing without issue.  I'm doing the following:

JQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '#promotionbtn', function() {
            $.get('./ajax_get_promotion.pl', {'promo':$('select.promoselect').val() }, function(data) {
                    $('.result').html(data);
            });
});
```

Perl:
    #!/usr/bin/perl

```
use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
require "./lib/servervars.pl";
require "./lib/common.pl";

#my $cgi = new CGI;

#print $cgi->header;

our $dbh;

my $promotion_code = param('promo');

my $promo_handle = "select PromoCode, FirstBillDate, DaysWaivedBilling,  RegistrationFee, RegistrationFeePaidBy, RegistrationDiscountPct, InvoiceDiscountPct, ReferralFee, PromotionTitle, PromotionMessage from Promotion where PromoCode='COMATTACH1'";
my $promotion;

my $getpromo = &db_connect($promo_handle);
while (my @promos = $getpromo->fetchrow) {
    $promotion .= "$promos[0]";
}

$getpromo->finish;

print "content-type:text/html\n\n";
print $promotion;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console to see what data is coming across?

Comment: your content type should be provided as Content-type:text/html\n\n;. Also you could use var $q = new CGI; print $q->header(); If you look at Firebug or another debugger tool can you see the request hitting the page? What is the header being returned? Also you are returning `<tr><td>` which are supposed to be in a table not defined for divs. Either wrap the content in the columns in `<p>` or make `div.result` a table or you may get unexpected results...

Comment: IF I run the script in console it prints the header and the TR TD line without issue. I've also tried throwing an alert to just see any data, but that shows up blank also. If I change it to $promotion .= "$promos[0]";  I still get the blank result

Comment: I updated my above code.  I'm letting CGI print my header and I've simplified what I'm printing even further.  It does seem to replace "Data:" inside the div when a select a drop down option and click the button.  Unfortunately it replaces it with nothing lol.

Comment: if you know that the `get` is returning try console.log("results: ", data) and see what is being returned. Alternatively i strongly suggest taking a look at the network tab in firebug or chrome developer tools or using fiddler to watch the request being made. You can get the headers and find out what exactly is being sent to the server and returned.

Comment: ok i will try that and report back. thx very much for the help

Comment: OK, so I made some insignificant changes to my code, like switched to CGI qw standard and made the c in content type lower case.  And it magically works.  I updated my code above, but seriously what the heck.  I was at home yesterday and using IE8, at work I'm in IE9 and latest Firefox.  But my .get() for email validation was functioing fine in IE8.  Thanks for the help.